# Калькулятор с условиями для сайта

Tags: javascript, условия, калькулятор

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать условия вывода результата на сайте при вводе чисел.
Условия такие: если вводимое число=<0.1 то результат=550; если вводимое число=>0.1 то результат="Индивидуальный тариф".

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"
oninput=" 
document.getElementById('rezultat').innerHTML 
= 
???
>
Введите расчётную тепловую нагрузку (Гкал/час) <input id="a" type="number">  
Цена (руб.) <output id="rezultat"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: `if  (summa < 0.1) { alert("550"); }else{ alert("индивидуальный тариф"); }`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var input = document.getElementById('a');

    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      var val = input.value;
      var rate = 'Индивидуальный тариф';
    
      if (val != null) {      
        if (val*1 < 0.1) {
          rate = '550';
        }
      } else {
          rate = '';
      }

      var rEl = document.getElementById('rezultat');
      rEl.innerHTML = rate;
    });
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  Введите расчётную тепловую нагрузку (Гкал/час) <input id="a" type="number"> Цена (руб.) <output id="rezultat"></output>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var input = document.getElementById('a'); 
    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      var val = input.value;
      if (val != null) { var rate = (val*1 < 0.1) ? '550' : 'Индивидуальный тариф';}
      var rEl = document.getElementById('rezultat');
      rEl.innerHTML = rate;
    })
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  Введите расчётную тепловую нагрузку (Гкал/час) <input id="a" type="number"> Цена (руб.) <output id="rezultat"></output>
</form>
```